# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE results into Table Type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to have an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE return its results into an table type (AS TABLE OF)

If the execute immediate returns a single value i am able to save the result using "INTO somevariable"

But, my execute immediate will return a multi column table and no amount of googling have help me figure it out!

First I create the types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_VALIDITY_RECORD AS OBJECT (
   TIME_COL  DATE,
   VALUE_COL NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_VALIDITY_TABLE AS TABLE OF T_VALIDITY_RECORD;
/
```

Then I attempt the code

```
DECLARE
   RET_TABLE   T_VALIDITY_TABLE;
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT my_date,
                          my_numbers  
                   FROM   my_table
                   WHERE  somthing = somthingelse' INTO RET_TABLE;
END;
```

This is just a really simplified example, the real code does (will do other things)

I've tried various things like BULK COLLECT INTO etc but can't seem to get it working.

I am getting the following error:

> Error report
>   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
>   ORA-06512: at line 5
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `BULK COLLECT INTO` and you need to collect instances of `T_VALIDITY_OBJECT` not pairs of `NUMBER` and `DATE` values.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_VALIDITY_RECORD AS OBJECT (
   VALUE_COL NUMBER,
   TIME_COL  DATE
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_VALIDITY_TABLE AS TABLE OF T_VALIDITY_RECORD;
/

CREATE TABLE my_table ( my_date, my_number, something ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-01-02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2019-01-03', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL**:

```sql
DECLARE
  RET_TABLE   T_VALIDITY_TABLE;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT T_VALIDITY_RECORD( my_date, my_number )
                     FROM   my_table
                     WHERE  something = :value'
    BULK COLLECT INTO RET_TABLE
    USING 1;

  FOR i IN 1 .. RET_TABLE.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ': ' || ret_table(i).time_col || ', ' || ret_table(i).value_col );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> 1: 2019-01-01 00:00:00, 1
> 2: 2019-01-02 00:00:00, 2
> 3: 2019-01-03 00:00:00, 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea17403166f318fa0ec8114ece7a57f5)*

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

You are fetching two columns into a structure that only has one element, made by two values.

Also, if your select can give more than one row, you need a `BULK COLLECT`.

If you don't need strictly dynamic sql here, a plain SQL query will work:

```
DECLARE
   RET_TABLE   T_VALIDITY_TABLE;
BEGIN    
    SELECT T_VALIDITY_RECORD(my_date, my_numbers  )
          bulk collect INTO RET_TABLE
   FROM   my_table ;
END;
```

If you need dynamic sql for other reasons:

```
DECLARE
   RET_TABLE   T_VALIDITY_TABLE;
BEGIN
    execute immediate ' SELECT T_VALIDITY_RECORD(my_date,
                              my_numbers  )
                        FROM   my_table'   
          bulk collect INTO RET_TABLE;                   
END;
```

Comment: Thanks but my example above is simplified, I need to use execute immediate (as I'm dynamically creating the SQL part)

Is there a way to acheive that using execute immediate?